# C# and Javascript Pass DATA

Tags: javascript, c#, webmethod

My C# application provides the data and send it to a WebService, like this :

```
list.Add('cool'); //add value to the list
list.Add('whau'); //add value to the list
Service.sendList(list.ToArray()); //send list to the WebService called Service using the WebMethod  sendList()
```

and the way I retrieve this data through a WebService in a Javascript function is like this :

```
 WebService.getList(OnSucceeded,OnFailed);
 function OnSucceeded(result){
 var data = result[0];  //result[0] = 'cool';
 var data2 = result[1]; //result[1] = 'whau';
 }
 function OnFailed(result){
 //do nothing
 }
```

Now, I need my var data like this :

```
var data = [['january', 2,3],['february', 3,5],['march', 5, 10]];
```

How I need to send it from C# to the WebService in order to have at the end a var data like just above ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: try using an object list: List<object> list = new List<object>(); list.Add(new object[]{"january", 2, 3}); //...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to send the data as a two-dimensional array.

```
var list = new List<List<string>>();
list.Add(new List<string>());

list[0].Add("january");
list[0].Add("2");
list[0].Add("3");
...
Service.sendList(list.ToArray());
```

Or, more succinctly, like this:

```
var list = new List<List<string>>();
list.Add(new List<string>(new string[] { "february", "3", "5" }));
...
Service.sendList(list.ToArray());
```

And of course, you can always parse the integers in JavaScript as follows:

```
parseInt(data[0][1], 10); // parses "2" into 2 (base 10)
```

Comment: @Johny_Rose Thanks for your help ! I ll try that soon ! I have an example of what I need in var data : http://jsfiddle.net/anh2gs7w/2/   Do you really think your method in order to send data like above will work ?